# javafx how to refresh table after adding record

Tags: javafx

i saw so many answers but its not suitable with me because i am using loop to generate my table not specific class
i want to refresh the table who generate the data from a loop.

i tried to refresh table but now working
i tried to build date again but it duplicates the table

### Here is where cells generated by a loop

```
            while(rs.next()){
                //Iterate Row
                 ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                    //Iterate Column
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
                data.add(row);
                table.setItems(data);

            }
```

### Here is add button

```
        buttonAdd.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t){
            try {
                stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT into stock VALUES('"
                + fieldCategoryID.getText()+ "','" + fieldCategoryName.getText() + "','" + fieldAmount.getText() + "','" + fieldCostPrice.getText()+ "','" + fieldSellingPrice.getText()
                        + "','" + fieldCategoryProfit.getText()+ "','" + fieldSupplier.getText()+ "','" + fieldCategoryProfitRate.getText()+
                        "','" + fieldTotalCategoryProfit.getText()+"','" + fieldOnStock.getText()+ "')");

        content.getChildren().removeAll(table);
        table.refresh();
        content.getChildren().add(table);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Stock.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        });
```

### Here is delete button

```
  buttonDelete.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t){
            try {
                                Alert alertConfirmation = new 
table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

                TablePosition pos = (TablePosition) table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
                            int row = pos.getRow();
                            TableColumn col = pos.getTableColumn();
                             String data = (String) col.getCellObservableValue(table.getItems().get(row)).getValue();
                String query = "DELETE FROM stock where category_code = ?";
                pst = con.prepareStatement(query); 
                pst.setString(1, data);
                pst.execute(); 
}
```

Comment: You're not modifying the `items` in the event handler for `buttonAdd`. Why would the content of the `TableView` change? Furthermore removing the `TableView` from the parent layout is not necessary for refreshing it. If you get duplicate entries in your other attempt, you've probably simply added the new items to the same list without clearing it. (An alternative would be to create a new `ObservableList` and replacing the `items` list, but this shouldn't be necessary.)

Comment: the items is generated by a loop that gets the data directly from the database, that's why i didn't modify it.
sorry because i am so beginner on java and taking my first steps.
i need a simple and clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

**i add a refresh method that clear observableList data Then i declare Statement and ResultSet again then added rows again**

```
public void refreshTable() throws SQLException{
data.clear();
stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
      rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from stock");
      while(rs.next()){
                //Iterate Row
                  row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
                for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
                    //Iterate Column
                    row.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );
                data.add(row);
                table.setItems(data);

            }   
}
```